# can't install myeclipse on macbookpro(yosemite)

Tags: java, osx-yosemite, myeclipse

When I update to Yosemite,I find out that i can't install myEclipse again.
  Installation error:insufficient memory,zero virtual memory.

And I tried the `sysctl vm.swapusage` command

 the result is `vm.swapusage: total = 0.00M  used = 0.00M  free = 0.00M  (encrypted)` .

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest MyEclipse 2015 CI release has been rebuilt. Download it, it should now install. It did for me, after the previous one failed in the way you mention.

Comment: Thanks.It works.However do u know why my total swap space is 0. Just confused of the difference between swap space and virtual memory. :)

Comment: Sorry, it's a mystery to me, too. It looks like the Mac uses virtual memory regardless of the swap settings. But, for some reason the MyEclipse installer only saw swap space, which is zero.